# Using React Big Calendar how can i change the color of the cell that i am pointing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to change all of these color.

It would be very helpful if you give me a sample code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

@heukma It's difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems to me what you are looking for is the [slotPropGetter](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-slotPropGetter) prop. This will allow you to provide custom classes or styles to slots, based upon the date you pass in.

```js
// your arrow function can contain custom logic, as long
// as it returns an object with either the `className` or
// `style` keys (or both). `className` must be a string, while `style`
// must be an object.
slotPropGetter={(date) => ({
  className: 'some-custom-class', 
  style: {
    backGroundColor: 'periwinkle'
  }
})}
```